# Unable to connect Google TPU VM to local jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, port, google-compute-engine, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect a Google cloud tpu VM instance to a local jupyter notebook. The purpose of this is to connect a colab notebook to my the GCP VM.

I have followed all the steps here

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Additionally, I have followed all the steps in this medium article as well.

https://medium.com/@senthilnathangautham/colab-gcp-compute-how-to-link-them-together-98747e8d940e

Except instead of setting those options at the creation of the VM, I edited an already created VM, since I didn't see those options when I created the TPU, but I was able to set all of those options (allow on HTTP and HTTPS traffic, In the metadata section add enable-oslogin as TRUE and also in the panel MetaData).

However, the local jupyter notebook only connects to my desktop, not the VM.

I am wondering if there's something wrong with the port forwarding.

I tried this command as mentioned in the first guide

```
gcloud compute ssh mytpuinstancename --zone=europe-west4-a -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
```

The connection to the VM TPU instance is fine, I can run training from the putty window, but I can't connect to the VM using using jupyter/colab.

I was wondering if I had to do anything else during the creation of my TPU VM, so I looked at the ctpu doc

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/ctpu-reference

And it seems that by default port forwarding is enabled.

> --forward-ports
> Automatically forward useful ports from the Compute Engine VM to your local machine. Ports forwarded are: 6006 (tensorboard), 8888 (jupyter notebooks), 8470 (TPU port), 8466 (TPU profiler port). (default = true)

Since the Jupyter notebook can connect to local, and since there is not much error in making a command that has port forwarding, I figured that something is wrong with my local computer.

From googling, it looks like I may need to release a port from the firewall, so I followed the instructions here to do so

https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/cofirewalls.htm

But the jupyter notebook still only connects to local. Finally, I tried to connect colab to the jupyter notebook address/token, but it only connected to local.

Comment: So - is my understanding correct - you can ping and SSH into your GCP VM from your local computer but your notebook connects only to the local jupyter notebook ?

Comment: Yes, that is my situation exactly. It only connects to my local computer, Not the GCP VM.

Comment: Can you explain what you exactly did to connect it to your GCP VM ? Did you get any error message ?

Comment: I used `gcloud compute ssh mytpuinstancename --zone=europe-west4-a -- -L 8888:localhost:8888`

There was no error message. The connected worked and I was able to run commands

Comment: Try creating your TPU VM with `oslogin-enable` set to `TRUE` - do it at the creation time. This is quite powerful feature and it may be at fault here. But that's just an educated guess. And fallow second tutorial from the start - make sure everything goes as described.